image to ascii art with edge detection using the sobel filter in python using pygame not rotated correctly
I have to layers of ascii art, one for the sobel filter, one for the general ascii art. I then overlap then and, because the sobel filter is initially only 0, using a simpe filter. The code works for some images but not for others. It seems to snap the images to be vertically the smallest. for example the linux mint logo works, but the ubuntu logo not. main:
import pygame
import sys
import math
import sobel
import numpy as np

pygame.init()

chars = '.,*+#@'



if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    print("-p           [path]")
    print("-c           activate colormode")
    print("-s           set the divide size, 10 by default")
    sys.exit()


path = None
colorized = False
n = 1
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    print(arg)
    if arg == "-c":
        colorized = True
    elif arg[0:2] == "-s":
        n = int(arg[2:])
    elif arg[0:2] == "-p":
        path = arg[2:]

if path is None:
    print("please specify a image path using -[path]")
    sys.exit()

try:
    img = pygame.image.load(path)
except:
    print(f"couldnt load the image at {path}")
    sys.exit()

img = pygame.transform.scale_by(img, n)
img = pygame.transform.scale_by(img, 1 / 8)

imgrect = img.get_rect()

outline = sobel.getoutline(path, n)
picture = []

for x in range(math.ceil(imgrect.width /  2)):
    row = ""

    for y in range(math.ceil(imgrect.height)):
        pixel = img.get_at((min(imgrect.width, x * 2),y))
        brightness = pixel.grayscale()
    
        char = chars[round(brightness.g / (255 / len(chars))) - 1]
        row += char
    picture.append(row)

picture: list[str] = picture

newpicture = []

for y in range(len(picture) - 1):
    row = ""
    for x in range(len(picture[y]) - 1):
        char = picture[y][x]
        outchar = outline[y][x]
        if outchar == "0":
            row += char
        else:
            row += outchar
    newpicture.append(row)

charlist = []

for row in newpicture:
    charlist.append(list(row))

np.rot90(charlist, 1, axes=(0,1))

finalpicture = []

for y in range(len(charlist)):
    row = ""
    for x in range(len(charlist[y])):
        char = charlist[y][x]
        if colorized:
            color = img.get_at((x, math.ceil(y * 2))) 
            row += f"\033[38;2;{color.r};{color.g};{color.b}m{char}\033[0m"
        else:
            row += char
    finalpicture.append(row)


for row in finalpicture:
    print(row)

print(len(finalpicture[0]))

sobel:
    import pygame
import sys
import time
import numpy as np

pygame.init()

def greyscale(surface: pygame.Surface):
    arr = pygame.surfarray.array3d(surface)
    # calulates the avg of the "rgb" values, this reduces the dim by 1
    mean_arr = np.mean(arr, axis=2)
    # restores the dimension from 2 to 3
    mean_arr3d = mean_arr[..., np.newaxis]
    # repeat the avg value obtained before over the axis 2
    new_arr = np.repeat(mean_arr3d[:, :, :], 3, axis=2)
    # return the new surface
    return pygame.surfarray.make_surface(new_arr)


def sobel(path: str, n: int): #path to image, image scale
    try:
        img = pygame.image.load(path)
    except:
        print(f"couldnt load the image at {path}")
        sys.exit()

    img = pygame.transform.scale_by(img, n)

            
    imgmap = [[] for _ in range(img.width)]
    for x in range(img.width):
        for y in range(img.height):
            color = img.get_at((x,y)).b
            color = (round(color / (255 / 2)) - 1) * 255
            imgmap[x].append(color)

    img = pygame.transform.scale_by(img, 1 / 8)

    imgmap = [[] for _ in range(img.width)]
    for x in range(img.width):
        for y in range(img.height):
            color = img.get_at((x,y)).b
            color = (round(color / (255 / 2)) - 1) * 255
            imgmap[x].append(color)

    picture = ["0" * img.width * 2 for _ in range(img.height)]



    for x in range(img.height):
        for y in range(img.height):
            Gx, Gy = 0,0
            try:
                Gx = (imgmap[x-1][y + 1] + 2 * imgmap[x-1][y] + imgmap[x-1][y - 1]) - (imgmap[x+1][y + 1] + 2 * imgmap[x+1][y] + imgmap[x+1][y - 1])
            except IndexError:
                pass
            try:
                Gy = (imgmap[x-1][y - 1] + 2 * imgmap[x][y - 1] + imgmap[x + 1][y - 1]) - (imgmap[x-1][y + 1] + 2 * imgmap[x-1][y] + imgmap[x-1][y - 1])
            except IndexError:
                pass

            char = "0"

            if abs(Gx) < 500:
                Gx = 0
            if abs(Gy) < 500:
                Gy = 0

            if Gx != 0:
                Gx = Gx / abs(Gx)
            if Gy != 0:
                Gy = Gy / abs(Gy)
            direction = [Gx, Gy]
            if direction != [0,0]:
                '''
                if direction == [1,-1] or direction == [-1,0]:
                    char = "|"
                elif direction == [0,1] or direction == [0,-1]:
                    char = "-"
                elif direction == [-1,1] or direction == [1,0]:
                    char = chr(92)
                elif direction == [-1,-1] or direction == [1,1]:
                    char = "/"
                '''

                if direction == [0,1]:
                    char = "~"
                elif direction == [1,0]:
                    char = "/"
                elif direction == [0,-1]:
                    char = "~"
                elif direction == [-1,0]:
                    char = "/"
                elif direction == [1,1]:
                    char = "~"
                elif direction == [1,-1]:
                    char = chr(92)
                elif direction == [-1,-1]:
                    char = "~"
                elif direction == [-1,1]:
                    char = chr(92)
            if char != "0":
                row = list(picture[y])
                row[x * 2] = char
                row[x * 2 + 1] = char
                picture[y] = "".join(row)


            #if direction != [0,0]:
                #pygame.draw.circle(img, (255 * abs(direction[0]), 255 * abs(direction[1]), 0), (x,y), 1)

    return picture

def getoutline(path, n):
    picture = sobel(path, n / 2)
    return picture

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()
    picture = sobel("/home/nosch/Documents/mint.png", 1.5)
    print(time.time()- start)
    #screen = pygame.display.set_mode((img.width, img.height))
    #screen.blit(img, (0,0))
    #pygame.display.flip()
    for row in picture:
        print(row)
        pass

mint logo:

ubuntu logo:

i tried to rotate the image using numpy, but it was still the same. i also drew without color but that didnt change anything.

I rotated the image in a way that broke it, the fixed version is:
main:
import pygame
import sys
import math
import sobel
import numpy as np

pygame.init()

chars = '.,*+#@'



if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    print("-p           [path]")
    print("-c           activate colormode")
    print("-s           set the divide size, 10 by default")
    sys.exit()


path = None
colorized = False
n = 1
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    print(arg)
    if arg == "-c":
        colorized = True
    elif arg[0:2] == "-s":
        n = int(arg[2:])
    elif arg[0:2] == "-p":
        path = arg[2:]

if path is None:
    print("please specify a image path using -[path]")
    sys.exit()


try:
    img = pygame.image.load(path)
except:
    print(f"couldnt load the image at {path}")
    sys.exit()

img = pygame.transform.scale_by(img, n)
img = pygame.transform.scale_by(img, 1 / 8)

imgrect = img.get_rect()

#generating outline
outline = sobel.getoutline(path, n)

#generating ascii
picture = []
for y in range(math.ceil(imgrect.height / 2)):
    row = ""

    for x in range(imgrect.width):
        pixel = img.get_at((x,y * 2))
        brightness = pixel.grayscale()
        
        char = chars[round(brightness.g / (255 / len(chars))) - 1]
        row += char
    picture.append(row)

picture: list[str] = picture

for row in picture:
    print(row)

for row in outline:
    print(row)

# generating ascii with outline
newpicture = []
for y in range(len(picture) - 1):
    row = ""
    for x in range(len(picture[y]) - 1):
        char = picture[y][x]
        outchar = outline[y][x]
        if outchar == "0":
            row += char
        else:
            row += outchar
    newpicture.append(row)

charlist = []

for row in newpicture:
    charlist.append(list(row))

finalpicture = []


# coloring ascii
for y in range(len(charlist)):
    row = ""
    for x in range(len(charlist[y])):
        char = charlist[y][x]
        if colorized:
            color = img.get_at((x, math.ceil(y * 2))) 
            row += f"\033[38;2;{color.r};{color.g};{color.b}m{char}\033[0m"
        else:
            row += char
    finalpicture.append(row)


for row in finalpicture:
    print(row)

sobel:
import pygame
import sys
import time
import numpy as np

pygame.init()

def greyscale(surface: pygame.Surface):
    arr = pygame.surfarray.array3d(surface)
    # calulates the avg of the "rgb" values, this reduces the dim by 1
    mean_arr = np.mean(arr, axis=2)
    # restores the dimension from 2 to 3
    mean_arr3d = mean_arr[..., np.newaxis]
    # repeat the avg value obtained before over the axis 2
    new_arr = np.repeat(mean_arr3d[:, :, :], 3, axis=2)
    # return the new surface
    return pygame.surfarray.make_surface(new_arr)


def sobel(path: str, n: int): #path to image, image scale
    try:
        img = pygame.image.load(path)
    except:
        print(f"couldnt load the image at {path}")
        sys.exit()

    img = pygame.transform.scale_by(img, n)
    img = pygame.transform.scale_by(img, 1 / 8)

            
    imgmap = [[] for _ in range(img.width)]
    for x in range(img.width):
        for y in range(img.height):
            color = img.get_at((x,y)).b
            color = (round(color / (255 / 2)) - 1) * 255
            imgmap[x].append(color)


    imgmap = [[] for _ in range(img.width)]
    for x in range(img.width):
        for y in range(img.height):
            color = img.get_at((x,y)).b
            color = (round(color / (255 / 2)) - 1) * 255
            imgmap[x].append(color)

    picture = ["0" * img.width * 2 for _ in range(img.height)]



    for x in range(img.height):
        for y in range(img.height):
            Gx, Gy = 0,0
            try:
                Gx = (imgmap[x-1][y + 1] + 2 * imgmap[x-1][y] + imgmap[x-1][y - 1]) - (imgmap[x+1][y + 1] + 2 * imgmap[x+1][y] + imgmap[x+1][y - 1])
            except IndexError:
                pass
            try:
                Gy = (imgmap[x-1][y - 1] + 2 * imgmap[x][y - 1] + imgmap[x + 1][y - 1]) - (imgmap[x-1][y + 1] + 2 * imgmap[x-1][y] + imgmap[x-1][y - 1])
            except IndexError:
                pass

            char = "0"

            if abs(Gx) < 500:
                Gx = 0
            if abs(Gy) < 500:
                Gy = 0

            if Gx != 0:
                Gx = Gx / abs(Gx)
            if Gy != 0:
                Gy = Gy / abs(Gy)
            direction = [Gx, Gy]
            if direction != [0,0]:
                '''
                if direction == [1,-1] or direction == [-1,0]:
                    char = "|"
                elif direction == [0,1] or direction == [0,-1]:
                    char = "-"
                elif direction == [-1,1] or direction == [1,0]:
                    char = chr(92)
                elif direction == [-1,-1] or direction == [1,1]:
                    char = "/"
                '''

                if direction == [0,1]:
                    char = "~"
                elif direction == [1,0]:
                    char = "/"
                elif direction == [0,-1]:
                    char = "~"
                elif direction == [-1,0]:
                    char = "/"
                elif direction == [1,1]:
                    char = "~"
                elif direction == [1,-1]:
                    char = chr(92)
                elif direction == [-1,-1]:
                    char = "~"
                elif direction == [-1,1]:
                    char = chr(92)
            if char != "0":
                row = list(picture[y])
                row[x * 2] = char
                row[x * 2 + 1] = char
                picture[y] = "".join(row)


            #if direction != [0,0]:
                #pygame.draw.circle(img, (255 * abs(direction[0]), 255 * abs(direction[1]), 0), (x,y), 1)

    return picture

def getoutline(path, n):
    picture = sobel(path, n / 2)
    return picture

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()
    picture = sobel("/home/nosch/Documents/mint.png", 1.5)
    print(time.time()- start)
    #screen = pygame.display.set_mode((img.width, img.height))
    #screen.blit(img, (0,0))
    #pygame.display.flip()
    for row in picture:
        print(row)

